# USB 3 XIMEA Camera xiQ: error while installing software package in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, software-installation, camera

I recently bought a XIMEA xiQ USB 3 Camera. It's working in Windows properly but when I try to use it in Ubuntu I get errors as below, although I followed [these instructions on the Ximea website](https://www.ximea.com/support/wiki/apis/XIMEA_Linux_Software_Package)

```
$ /opt/XIMEA/bin/xiCamTool
xiAPI: XIMEA Camera API V4.13.18.00 
xiAPI: Adding camera context: dwID=11600851 ptr=880B4000 processID=00000BCA 
xiAPI: Create handles 1 Process 00000BCA 
xiAPI: Enable sensor 
xiAPI: xiReadFileFFS 'SensFPNCorrections' not found 
xiAPI: ScmCorrectorA::LoadAndParseConfigurationFile Warning: file SensFPNCorrections not found 
xiAPI: xiReadFileFFS 'SensFPNCorrections' not found 
xiAPI: ScmCorrectorA::LoadAndParseConfigurationFile Warning: file SensFPNCorrections not found 
xiAPI: Frequency 114 71 xiAPI: Enabled 1 bandwidth 48000000 
xiAPI: Time needed to read BPL:142ms 
xiAPI: Successfully parsed BPL file, 1829 total corrected pixels 
xiAPI: SetGPIO 1 set to 8 xiAPI: Frequency 50 31 
xiAPI: Enabled 1 bandwidth 48000000 
xiAPI: SetGPIO 1 set to 0 
xiAPI: AutoSetBandwidth measurement 
xiAPI: CalculateResources : Context 880B4000 ID 11600851 m_maxBytes=512 m_maxBufferSize=524288 
xiAPI: Failed to change thread scheduler, check user limit for realtime priority. 
xiAPI: AutoSetBandwidth measured 393Mbps. Safe margin 10% will be used. 
xiAPI: Current bandwidth limit auto-set to 353 Mbps (min:80Mbps,max:393Mbps) 
xiAPI: Frequency 50 31 
xiAPI: Enabled 1 bandwidth 44125000 
xiAPI: Frequency 46 2d 
xiAPI: Enabled 1 bandwidth 44125000 
xiAPI: ---- Device opened. Model:MQ013CG-E2 SN:11600851 FwF1:API:V4.13.18.00 ---- 
xiAPI: XIA(8150):xiGetParam (hdr) Finished with ERROR: 106 0x7ff69bebd940 ../../src/xiViewer/xiCore/xiApiWrapper.cpp L 338 : "xiApi_GetParamInt(): xiGetParamInt(hdr) returned 106" 
xiAPI: XIA(8150):xiGetParam (hdr_kneepoint1:min) Finished with ERROR: 106 0x7ff69bebd940 ../../src/xiViewer/xiCore/xiApiWrapper.cpp L 338 : "xiApi_GetParamInt(): xiGetParamInt(hdr_kneepoint1:min) returned 106" 
xiAPI: XIA(8150):xiGetParam (hdr_kneepoint1:max) Finished with ERROR: 106 0x7ff69bebd940 ../../src/xiViewer/xiCore/xiApiWrapper.cpp L 338 : "xiApi_GetParamInt(): xiGetParamInt(hdr_kneepoint1:max) returned 106"
```

Comment: Root process also give me "Warning: file SensFPNCorrections not found " & error "106"

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I recently try to install software package in Ubuntu 14.04 & it look like working fine although I'm still getting error "xiAPI: XIA(4510):xiSetParam (gpi_selector) Finished with ERROR: 11"    I'm using XIMEA xiQ USB3, Serial Number: 11600851.

Comment: Why it's not working in 16.04

Comment: If you have any issues with XIMEA products, please create a support ticket in the XIMEA public tracker: https://www.ximea.com/support where our support personnel will help you to solve the issue. Also please include the information about installed SW package version, camera model and serial number. Thank you. Best regards, XIMEA Team

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I was actually setting this up on a similar environment earlier. Linux has default memory buffer limits on USB, and they had to be removed for the Ximea stuff to work.

This command temporarily removes the limits, so run it in terminal before the API stuff:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/usbfs_memory_mb
```

This is from a warning the API gives when installing on Linux.